# how to redirect port 80 to another port

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, portforwarding

I set up 3 containers in a VM using docker

the first one is a WordPress page hosted on port 5050
the second is a PHPMyAdmin page hosted on port 5000
The last one is Nginx server hosted on port 80

all the containers work fine but I want to set the third container (nginx) in port 80 to forward all the request based on the path link for example:

`localhost/wordpress` =forworded to=> port 5050 where WordPress hosted
the same for phpMyAdmin

this is what I got to so far: `default.conf`

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    root                    /var/www/localhost/htdocs/;
    index                   index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name             _;
    client_max_body_size    32m;
    error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root              /var/lib/nginx/html;
    }
    location /wordpress{
              proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5050;  
    }
    location /phpmyadmin{
              proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;  
    }
}
```

the error I got :
[image]

NOTE: all the phpMyadmin and WordPress had Nginx server setup on the same container among WordPress and PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Can you show the configuration for each of the three Docker containers?  Also, what is not working?  Are you receiving a specific error?

Comment: yeap when I start the three containers they start fine and I can access all of them but using the port `http://localhost:5050` to go to WordPress but I want to access them using the link (the Nginx container redirect to every container) like the example I gave in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `/` at the end

```
location /wordpress{
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5050/;  
}
location /phpmyadmin{
          proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000/;  
}
```